# Update / echo dont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I don't understand why this doesn't work :

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET balance = balance - 250 WHERE userID = <?php echo $row['userID']; ?>";
```

I work with PDO

What is wrong here? Need some help

```
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in()) {
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$servername = "test.de.mysql";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "test";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET balance = balance - 250 WHERE userID = <?php echo $row['userID']; ?>";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Comment: Um.... you're already in PHP here `<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>` and should have gotten an error about it; a PARSE error.

Comment: I dont go a error!You can see it here. kevinshop.de/test.1php

Comment: that's because you're not checking via the PHP method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- and how can I this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET balance = balance - 250 WHERE userID = " . intval($row['userID']);
```

Also i would mention you select all the userFields while you only need userID which is unnecessary mem waste.